# My Bootloader Mode Goes Into Charging Mode After 5 Sseconds

Tags: android, bootloader, unlock

When I go into bootloader mode for the cmd part in my XPERIA SP, the phone goes into bootloading for some seconds and then it starts charging. The blue light becomes orange in other words, so I don't have time to install the fastboot drivers or finish the unlocking process.

Please tell me what I need to do in order for my Xperia SP, to stay in bootloader mode and not go into charging mode instead.

I already activated the USB debugging and the developer options and downloaded all drivers and SDK MANAGER... But I can't get my phone to stay with the blue light on for more than 5 seconds.

Comment: This actually is on topic, as fastboot is the tool used by someone who has developed software in the form of a custom build of Android to load their work onto the device.  As for the problem, it is unclear if your device supports this, however a Linux system would let you pre-install fastboot and its udev rule (no "driver" is used there), allowing you to send a command within the timeout, if that is actually what you need to do.  Or if you have an embedded development board with USB handy you could load it up with an example cloning that VID&PID and install the driver against that at leisure.

Comment: This does not sound like an Android bootloader but rather the QCOM bootloader instead. Are you sure you know what you are trying to do?